# How to upload a file to node express server chunk based

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i have an express application that reads a file and stores it on the server. My server has nginx as a web server which has max_file_limit set to 1 MB. I do not have permissions to change the limit. So, when i make an api call with file more than 1 mb, it is failing due to the file size limit. To overcome this issue, i want to convert my file to chunks when the request is made. I am using multer to handle file uploads. How to make an apicall with chunks of data and handle that in my express application?